# How does datetime understand 53rd week?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

When assigning data to a specific year-week (using pandas 1.5.0), there is a surprising behavior (at least to me) around new years day and I wonder if I am doing something wrong, here is how I am computing the year and week for Jan 1 2021:

```
pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 00:10:00+00:00').year

>>> 2021

pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 00:10:00+00:00').week

>>> 53
```

The value of 2021 makes sense, and I could understand 53 as the 53rd week of 2020, but put together when I sort/plot the data by year-wake, this point ends up at the end of 2021.  Do I need to call year/week together to make sure they return a consistent answer?

Comment: I believe the commentary for [`datetime.date.isocalendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) is relevant here as well. Or just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: The isocalendar example makes sense, but doesn't it behave differently then above?  In the first link:    date(2003, 12, 29).isocalendar()
    datetime.IsoCalendarDate(year=2004, week=1, weekday=1).  since the date is the first week of 2004, the year and week are shifted, in my example, the week is shifted but not the year

Comment: I went the route: `import datetime as dt`, `dt.date(2021, 1, 1).isocalendar().week` returns 53.

Comment: Perfect!  Yes, adding isocalendar to year moves it to 2020, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding isocalendar() to the call appears to resolve the discrepency:

```
pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 00:10:00+00:00').isocalendar().year

>>> 2020

pd.to_datetime('2021-01-01 00:10:00+00:00').isocalendar().week

>>> 53
```

Answer (score 2):

`.weekofyear` and `.week` have been ***deprecated*** since version 1.1.0 (July 28, 2020). you can use `.isocalendar().week` to access the week instead.